# Ubuntu 14.04 - on the fly change operating system language while remotely support required

Tags: 14.04, kernel, remote-desktop, vnc, language-support

In Windows 8.1, OSX 10.9.4 and all other OS we cant do on the fly change operating system languages. We have purchased hardware from Japan, China, India etc etc for Europe, where organisation only speak dutch, french as a result the whole OS is configured only into Dutch or french.

But on other hand remotely technicians want to remotely login via TeamViewer or VNC from Japan, China, India and they stop giving support because they cant read the OS language in English.

We have tried Ubuntu 14.04 and its doing the same like all other operating system.

Can Linux/ Ubuntu 14.04 show the world that this challenge can be resolved via Linux, where others failed (Windows and OSX)?

How can i allow a Japan, China, Indian IT people to see my desktop in English where my OS was installed in French/Dutch/Arabic etc etc?

Answer (score 0):

You know that you can control the display language per user, don't you?

*System Settings -> Language Support*